# How to refresh ListView custom adapter data from the event listener that is in the adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am a beginner to Android. Now I am working with ListView using custom adapter and custom view. Custom adapter is created as into a separate file. But inside my custom adapter, I set up a click listener for a button of the layout of the list view row. But my problem is how can I update items of the adapter inside event listener that is created inside the custom adapter.

This is my Listview Fragment:

```
public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment {
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private TextView taskTitle;
    private ListView taskListView;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Task> items;
    private int optionFocusedItemIndex;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list, container, false);
        taskTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_textview);
        taskListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTaskList);
        int type = getArguments().getInt("type");
        switch (type){
            case R.integer.task_list_all:
                items = dbHelper.getAllTasks();
                adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(),items);
                taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                taskTitle.setText("All tasks");
                break;
        }
        taskListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int tagId = Integer.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());
                optionFocusedItemIndex = position;
                showOptionDialog(tagId);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void showOptionDialog(final int id)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_option_dialog, null);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        Button doneBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_done);
        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.markAsDone(id);
                refreshListView();
                alertDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Marked as done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Button editBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_edit);
        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
                activity.replaceEditTaskFragment(id);
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_delete);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.deleteTask(id);
                items.remove(optionFocusedItemIndex);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Task deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        Button cancelBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_cancel);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setView(view);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void refreshListView()
    {
        if(items!=null)
        {
            Task taskOld = items.get(optionFocusedItemIndex);
            if(taskOld!=null)
            {
                taskOld.setDone(true);
                items.set(optionFocusedItemIndex, taskOld);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the fragment, when I click the done button listView adapter is updated properly and it is working find. Done button is inside the AlertDialog box that appear when long click on one of the rows of list view.

The problem is here.

This is my custom adapter class:

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Task> values;
    private final DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    public TaskListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Task> values)
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list_row,parent, false);
        rowView.setTag(values.get(position).getId());
        TextView rowDescription = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_description);
        rowDescription.setText(values.get(position).getDescription());
        ImageView rowStatusIcon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_status_icon);

        Long currentDateMillSec= System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long dateMillSec = CommonHelper.convertStrDateToMilSec(values.get(position).getDate());//(date==null)?0:date.getTime();
        if(values.get(position).getDone()==Boolean.TRUE)
        {
           rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.done_icon);
        }
        else if(dateMillSec>0 && dateMillSec<currentDateMillSec)
        {
           rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.failed_icon);
        }
        else{
            rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_icon);
        }


        TextView dateTf = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_date);
        dateTf.setText(values.get(position).getDate());

        Button doneBtn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_done_btn);
        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.markAsDone(values.get(position).getId());
                //How can I update the listview items here ?

            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }


}
```

So how can I update the listview items and listview from the click event listener of done button that is inside custom adapter class.

Comment: You have the `list` in the adapter also, whatever you make changes in the list, either `add/remove/update` just use the same list and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, actually it is too simple. What I need to do is just add this code inside the click listener of done button in the custom adapter.

This is the click listener of the doneBtn in custom adapter:

```
doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.markAsDone(values.get(position).getId());
                //How can I update the listview items here ?
                if(values!=null)
                {
                    Task oldTask = values.get(position);
                    oldTask.setDone(Boolean.TRUE);
                    values.set(position,oldTask);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment implements TaskListAdapter.RefreshAdapter{//change
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private TextView taskTitle;
    private ListView taskListView;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Task> items;
    private int optionFocusedItemIndex;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list, container, false);
    taskTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_textview);
    taskListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTaskList);
    int type = getArguments().getInt("type");
    switch (type){
        case R.integer.task_list_all:
            items = dbHelper.getAllTasks();
            adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(),items);
            taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setRefreshAdapter(this);//change
            taskTitle.setText("All tasks");
            break;
    }
    taskListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int tagId = Integer.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());
            optionFocusedItemIndex = position;
            showOptionDialog(tagId);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
    }

    public void showOptionDialog(final int id)
    {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_option_dialog, null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
    Button doneBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_done);
    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbHelper.markAsDone(id);
            refreshListView();
            alertDialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Marked as done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Button editBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_edit);
    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            activity.replaceEditTaskFragment(id);
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_delete);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbHelper.deleteTask(id);
            items.remove(optionFocusedItemIndex);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Task deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    Button cancelBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_row_option_cancel);
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void refreshListView()
    {
    if(items!=null)
    {
        Task taskOld = items.get(optionFocusedItemIndex);
        if(taskOld!=null)
        {
            taskOld.setDone(true);
            items.set(optionFocusedItemIndex, taskOld);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    }

    //change
    @Override
    public void OnlickRefreshAdapter(){
    //todo your code here
    items = dbHelper.getAllTasks();
    adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(),items);
        taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

adapter class

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Task> values;
    private final DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private RefreshAdapter refreshAdapter;
    public TaskListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Task> values)
    {
    super(context,-1,values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

     public Interface RefreshAdapter{
        public void OnlickRefreshAdapter();
     }

     public setRefreshAdapter(RefreshAdapter refresh){
    refreshAdapter = refresh;
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list_row,parent, false);
    rowView.setTag(values.get(position).getId());
    TextView rowDescription = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_description);
    rowDescription.setText(values.get(position).getDescription());
    ImageView rowStatusIcon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_status_icon);

    Long currentDateMillSec= System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long dateMillSec = CommonHelper.convertStrDateToMilSec(values.get(position).getDate());//(date==null)?0:date.getTime();
    if(values.get(position).getDone()==Boolean.TRUE)
    {
       rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.done_icon);
    }
    else if(dateMillSec>0 && dateMillSec<currentDateMillSec)
    {
       rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.failed_icon);
    }
    else{
        rowStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.todo_icon);
    }


    TextView dateTf = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_date);
    dateTf.setText(values.get(position).getDate());

    Button doneBtn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_done_btn);
    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbHelper.markAsDone(values.get(position).getId());
            //How can I update the listview items here ?

        }
    });
    return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I call that refresh from the event listener please ?

Comment: if you have implemented the interface then set the adapter again just as you did the first time

Comment: i have edited the answer plz i have not compiled and checked so there may be minor mistakes such as syntax hope it works

Comment: sorry ther i missed this lines doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          dbHelper.markAsDone(values.get(position).getId());
          //How can I update the listview items here ?
   if(refreshAdapter!=null)
    refreshAdapter.OnlickRefreshAdapter();

      }
  });

Comment: But you did not do anything insdie the click listener of done button.

Comment: No . It is not what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101664/discussion-between-avinash-joshi-and-wai-yan-hein).

Comment: Please. Hold on. Thanks for helping me. I think I am about to get the solution.

Comment: I got the solution. Actually that is too simple. Not complicated like this. I am about to post the answer.